# using mysql in codeigniter library

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, libraries

How can I use the mysql instance inside of a library in codeigniter if I would like to execute queries. The class looks like

```
class Dtables {

    private $_db;

    function __construct()
    {
        //initialize $_db;

    }

    function mysql()
    {
        $sQuery ="//some mysql query string";
        $this->db->query($sQuery);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the CI object instance in your library:

```
class Dtables {

    private $CI;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->database(); 
    }

    function mysql()
    {
        $sQuery ="//some mysql query string";
        $this->CI->db->query($sQuery);
    }
}
```